# How to make code that resizes SwiftUI views using a drag gesture more performant?

Tags: performance, swiftui, drag

[image]

I am trying to use drag gestures to allow the user to both change the positions of views and to resize the views.  Dragging to move the views works well but the performance when dragging to resize is poor.  I can not figure out what the issues is.  I tried adding a drawingGroup() modifier to speed things up and that didn't really help either.  I didn't expect it to though because just moving a single, very simple view runs poorly.  I assume there's just something about how SwiftUI works that I don't understand.  I am having the performance issues running on a 2018 Core i3 Mac Mini.

```
@main
struct App: App {

@StateObject private var model = TestModel()

let info = CardComponentInfo(type: .text, origin: .init(x: 300, y: 300), size: .init(width: 200, height: 200))

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup("Ensemble") {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            TestComponentView(info: info, model: model)
        }
        .frame(width: 1000, height: 1000)
    }
}
}

struct TestComponentView: View {

var info: CardComponentInfo
@ObservedObject var model: TestModel

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Label(info.type.title, systemImage: info.type.systemImageName)
        ResizingControlsView { point, deltaX, deltaY in
            model.resizedComponentInfo = info
            model.updateForResize(using: point, deltaX: deltaX, deltaY: deltaY)
            //model.updateForResize(point: point, deltaX: deltaX, deltaY: deltaY) // other udpateForResize may work
        } dragEnded: {
            model.resizeEnded()
        }
    }
    .frame(
        width: model.widthForCardComponent(info: info),
        height: model.heightForCardComponent(info: info)
    )
    .background(info.type.color)
    .position(
        x: model.xPositionForCardComponent(info: info),
        y: model.yPositionForCardComponent(info: info)
    )
    .gesture(
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { gesture in
                model.draggedComponentInfo = info
                model.updateForDrag(deltaX: gesture.translation.width, deltaY: gesture.translation.height)
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                model.dragEnded()
            }
    )
}
}

class TestModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var componentInfos: [CardComponentInfo] = []

@Published var draggedComponentInfo: CardComponentInfo? = nil
@Published var dragOffset: CGSize? = nil

@Published var selectedComponentInfo: CardComponentInfo? = nil

@Published var selectedTypeToAdd: CardComponentViewType? = nil
@Published var componentBeingAddedInfo: CardComponentInfo? = nil

@Published var resizedComponentInfo: CardComponentInfo? = nil
@Published var resizeOffset: CGSize? = nil
@Published var resizePoint: ResizePoint? = nil

func widthForCardComponent(info: CardComponentInfo) -> CGFloat {
    let widthOffset = (resizedComponentInfo?.id == info.id) ? (resizeOffset?.width ?? 0.0) : 0.0
    return info.size.width + widthOffset
}

func heightForCardComponent(info: CardComponentInfo) -> CGFloat {
    let heightOffset = (resizedComponentInfo?.id == info.id) ? (resizeOffset?.height ?? 0.0) : 0.0
    return info.size.height + heightOffset
}

func xPositionForCardComponent(info: CardComponentInfo) -> CGFloat {
    let xPositionOffset = (draggedComponentInfo?.id == info.id) ? (dragOffset?.width ?? 0.0) : 0.0
    return info.origin.x + (info.size.width / 2.0) + xPositionOffset
}

func yPositionForCardComponent(info: CardComponentInfo) -> CGFloat {
    let yPositionOffset = (draggedComponentInfo?.id == info.id) ? (dragOffset?.height ?? 0.0) : 0.0
    return info.origin.y + (info.size.height / 2.0) + yPositionOffset
}

func updateForResize(point: ResizePoint, deltaX: CGFloat, deltaY: CGFloat) {
    resizeOffset = CGSize(width: deltaX, height: deltaY)
    resizePoint = resizePoint
}

func resizeEnded() {
    guard let resizedComponentInfo, let resizePoint, let resizeOffset else { return }
    var w: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.size.width
    var h: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.size.height
    var x: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.origin.x
    var y: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.origin.y
    switch resizePoint {
    case .topLeft:
        w -= resizeOffset.width
        h -= resizeOffset.height
        x += resizeOffset.width
        y += resizeOffset.height
    case .topMiddle:
        h -= resizeOffset.height
        y += resizeOffset.height
    case .topRight:
        w += resizeOffset.width
        h -= resizeOffset.height
    case .rightMiddle:
        w += resizeOffset.width
    case .bottomRight:
        w += resizeOffset.width
        h += resizeOffset.height
    case .bottomMiddle:
        h += resizeOffset.height
    case .bottomLeft:
        w -= resizeOffset.width
        h += resizeOffset.height
        x -= resizeOffset.width
        y += resizeOffset.height
    case .leftMiddle:
        w -= resizeOffset.width
        x += resizeOffset.width
    }
    resizedComponentInfo.size = CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    resizedComponentInfo.origin = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    self.resizeOffset = nil
    self.resizePoint = nil
    self.resizedComponentInfo = nil
}

func updateForDrag(deltaX: CGFloat, deltaY: CGFloat) {
    dragOffset = CGSize(width: deltaX, height: deltaY)
}

func dragEnded() {
    guard let dragOffset else { return }
    draggedComponentInfo?.origin.x += dragOffset.width
    draggedComponentInfo?.origin.y += dragOffset.height
    draggedComponentInfo = nil
    self.dragOffset = nil
}

func updateForResize(using resizePoint: ResizePoint, deltaX: CGFloat, deltaY: CGFloat) {
    
    guard let resizedComponentInfo else { return }
    
    var width: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.size.width
    var height: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.size.height
    var x: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.origin.x
    var y: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.origin.y
    switch resizePoint {
    case .topLeft:
        width -= deltaX
        height -= deltaY
        x += deltaX
        y += deltaY
    case .topMiddle:
        height -= deltaY
        y += deltaY
    case .topRight:
        width += deltaX
        height -= deltaY
        y += deltaY
        print(width, height, x)
    case .rightMiddle:
        width += deltaX
    case .bottomRight:
        width += deltaX
        height += deltaY
    case .bottomMiddle:
        height += deltaY
    case .bottomLeft: //
        width -= deltaX
        height += deltaY
        x += deltaX
    case .leftMiddle:
        width -= deltaX
        x += deltaX
    }
    resizedComponentInfo.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    resizedComponentInfo.origin = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
```

}

```
enum ResizePoint {
case topLeft, topMiddle, topRight, rightMiddle, bottomRight, bottomMiddle, bottomLeft, leftMiddle
```

}

struct ResizingControlsView: View {

```
let borderColor: Color = .white
let fillColor: Color = .blue
let diameter: CGFloat = 15.0
let dragged: (ResizePoint, CGFloat, CGFloat) -> Void
let dragEnded: () -> Void

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
        HStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            grabView(resizePoint: .topLeft)
            Spacer()
            grabView(resizePoint: .topMiddle)
            Spacer()
            grabView(resizePoint: .topRight)
        }
        Spacer()
        HStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            grabView(resizePoint: .leftMiddle)
            Spacer()
            grabView(resizePoint: .rightMiddle)
        }
        Spacer()
        HStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            grabView(resizePoint: .bottomLeft)
            Spacer()
            grabView(resizePoint: .bottomMiddle)
            Spacer()
            grabView(resizePoint: .bottomRight)
        }
    }
}

private func grabView(resizePoint: ResizePoint) -> some View {
    var offsetX: CGFloat = 0.0
    var offsetY: CGFloat = 0.0
    let halfDiameter = diameter / 2.0
    switch resizePoint {
    case .topLeft:
        offsetX = -halfDiameter
        offsetY = -halfDiameter
    case .topMiddle:
        offsetY = -halfDiameter
    case .topRight:
        offsetX = halfDiameter
        offsetY = -halfDiameter
    case .rightMiddle:
        offsetX = halfDiameter
    case .bottomRight:
        offsetX = +halfDiameter
        offsetY = halfDiameter
    case .bottomMiddle:
        offsetY = halfDiameter
    case .bottomLeft:
        offsetX = -halfDiameter
        offsetY = halfDiameter
    case .leftMiddle:
        offsetX = -halfDiameter
    }
    return Circle()
        .strokeBorder(borderColor, lineWidth: 3)
        .background(Circle().foregroundColor(fillColor))
        .frame(width: diameter, height: diameter)
        .offset(x: offsetX, y: offsetY)
        .gesture(dragGesture(point: resizePoint))
}

private func dragGesture(point: ResizePoint) -> some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged { drag in
            switch point {
            case .topLeft:
                dragged(point, drag.translation.width, drag.translation.height)
            case .topMiddle:
                dragged(point, 0, drag.translation.height)
            case .topRight:
                dragged(point, drag.translation.width, drag.translation.height)
            case .rightMiddle:
                dragged(point, drag.translation.width, 0)
            case .bottomRight:
                dragged(point, drag.translation.width, drag.translation.height)
            case .bottomMiddle:
                dragged(point, 0, drag.translation.height)
            case .bottomLeft:
                dragged(point, drag.translation.width, drag.translation.height)
            case .leftMiddle:
                dragged(point, drag.translation.width, 0)
            }
        }
        .onEnded { _ in dragEnded() }
}
}
```

Comment: Just a guess but why are you using optionals for your published values ?

Comment: @PtitXav because most of the time the user won't be resizing so the resizing values shouldn't exist / they should be nil.  I tried using non-optionals values and the performance is the same.

Comment: Please wrap your project into a minimal xcode project and make that available somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried using a drawingGroup modifier to render your view with Metal? try applying ".drawingGroup()" modifier to your main view

Comment: @MatiasContreras Yes, I already tried using a drawingGroup and saw no change in performance.

Comment: Could you provide a full working example to build and run on my side?

Comment: @MatiasContreras https://github.com/KevinBFrench/Resizing_ProblemApp

Comment: @Alnitak https://github.com/KevinBFrench/Resizing_ProblemApp

Comment: @KevinF it is empty

Comment: @MatiasContreras Oh, sorry about that.  The code should be there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `DragGesture` will read gestures within the most `local` coordinate space. In the case of your `ResizingControlsView` that would be the area within the green rectangle.

Unfortunately, under these conditions every time you resize the rectangle you are adjusting the coordinate space. `DragGesture` will register additional movement because the space has moved, which will trigger functions that further move the space, causing the registration of more movement, and so on—leading to a loop condition.

This can be solved pretty easily by substituting the following code in `ResizingControlsView.swift`:

```
...
private func dragGesture(point: ResizePoint) -> some Gesture {
    DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
        .onChanged { drag in
...
```

This solution works by monitoring the `global` coordinate space, which isn't affected by changes in the position of the green rectangle. However, that means the translated width and height it returns will no longer account for changes in offset like before.

To account for this, you'll need to subtract the previous offset (deltaX and deltaY) from the new offset manually within `updateForResize` each time it is called.

```
var previousResizeOffset: CGSize? = nil
...
func updateForResize(using resizePoint: ResizePoint, deltaX: CGFloat, deltaY: CGFloat) {
    guard let resizedComponentInfo else { return }
    
    var width: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.size.width
    var height: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.size.height
    var x: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.origin.x
    var y: CGFloat = resizedComponentInfo.origin.y
    
    // Adjust the values of deltaY and deltaX to mimic a local coordinate space.
    let adjDeltaY = deltaY - (previousResizeOffset?.height ?? 0)
    let adjDeltaX = deltaX - (previousResizeOffset?.width ?? 0)
    
    switch resizePoint {
    case .topLeft:
        width -= adjDeltaX
        height -= adjDeltaY
        x += adjDeltaX
        y += adjDeltaY
...
```

In my above example I have saved the previous deltaX and deltaY offsets in a variable, `previousResizeOffset`, and am subtracting it from new deltaX and deltaY offsets as they come in.

Comment: Thanks, @Shawn. Do these changes result in better performance for you? When I switch to using the global coordinateSpace and don't make the changes in the updateForResize function I don't see any change in performance and the rectangle is always the shape I expect.  With the default coordinateSpace and the global one the resizing results in the shape I expect.  When I make the changes to the coordinate space and to the updateForResizeFunction you recommend the app maxes out the CPU and freezes.

Comment: Yes I saw performance improvements in XCode 14.2 (14C18) using the Github project provided in the post comments. It shouldn't be possible for the updateForResize to work properly without changes if the coordinate space has changed. Video from simulator: https://imgur.com/jaXc9sy

Comment: That's the same version of Xcode I have.  Maybe my computer is just slow?  My original post shows a gif of it resizing to the correct shape and position using the default coordinate space

Comment: I misunderstood your answer the first time I read it.  Your solution does fix the performance issue.  Thank you!

Comment: @Shawn or @KevinF when do I set or update `previousResizeOffset`

Comment: @SamuelFolledo at the end of "updateForResize" I have "previousResizeOffset = .init(width: deltaX, height: deltaY)".  My "resizeEnded" is also just setting "previousResizeOffset", "resizePoint" and "resizedComponentInfo" to nil